# Show $4m^2+1$ and $2m+1$ are Co-Prime for integer $m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

Does this mean I need to show that $\gcd(4m^2+1, 2m+1) = 1$ ? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: $gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a \pm kb, b)$.

Comment: Yes, you want to show the gcd is 1. Taking the gcd of polynomials is a standard problem, so have you tried anything? e.g. searching "gcd of two polynomials"?

Comment: Use the Euclidean algorithm. That your numbers are given as expressions doesn't forbid it's use. Be careful with possible corner cases for $m$, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\gcd(A,B) = \gcd(A \pm kB, B)$

and $(4m^2 + 1)- 2m(2m+1) = -2m+1$

So $\gcd(4m^2 + 1, 2m+1) = \gcd([4m^2 +1] - 2m(2m+1), 2m+1) = \gcd(-2m+1, 2m+1)$.

Can you finish it from there  by figuring out what $\gcd(-2m+1, 2m+1)$ is?

If not notice that $(-2m + 1) +(2m+1) = 2$.

And notice that $(2m+1) -2m = 1$.

so can you finish from there?

....

If I wanted to be perverse and obscure I'd point out that

$1 = (2m+1) - [(4m^2 + 1) - 2m(2m+1) + (2m + 1)]*m$.

Does that remind you of anything?

What about

$(2m+1)\cdot (2m^2 - m +1) + (4m^2+1)\cdot(-m)=1$.

Remember Bezout's Lemma?

Answer (score 1):

If $4m^2+1$ and $2m+1$ are divisible by $d$ then $(2m+1)^2 - (4m^2+1) = 4m$ is also divisible by $d$.

Further, $4m - (2m+1) = 2m-1$ is also divisible by $d$, and therefore $(2m+1) - (2m-1) = 2$ is also divisible by $d$. Can you reach the conclusion from here?

Comment: So are you essentially applying the Euclidean algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

The extended Euclidean algorithm gives a denominator (see last line). Just think that $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2,$  as in:

$$ \left(  4 x^{2}  + 1 \right)   -  \left(  2 x  + 1 \right)  \left(    2 x  - 1   \right)  =  2  $$

==================================================

$$  \left(  4 x^{2}  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  2 x  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  4 x^{2}  + 1 \right)  =  \left(  2 x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(  2 x  - 1 \right) } +  \left( 2  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  2 x  + 1 \right)  =  \left( 2  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 2 x  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(  2 x  - 1 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(  2 x  - 1 \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 2 x  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 4 x^{2}  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 2 x  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(  4 x^{2}  + 1 \right)  \left( \frac{ 1}{2 } \right)  -  \left(  2 x  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 2 x  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $4m^2+1=(2m+1)(2m-1)+2$, so, if $d$ is a positive divisor of $4m^2+1$ and $2m+1, $

then $d|2$, so $d=1$ or $2$.  But $2\nmid 4m^2+1$, so that leaves $d=1$.

Comment: $(2m+1)(2m-1)=4m^2-1$, NOT $4m^2+1$

Comment: Yes, @KeithBackman, and that's why I wrote $\color{red}{+2}$

Comment: Oops! Snuck right by me.

Answer (score 0):

Case $\,n=2m\,$ even in: $ $ by Euclid $\overbrace{(\color{#0a0}{n^2+1},\,\color{#c00}{n+1})\, =\, (\color{#0a0}2,n+1)}^{\textstyle \color{#0a0}{f(\color{#c00}n)\equiv f(\color{#c00}{-1})}\,\pmod{\color{#c00}{n\equiv -1}}} = 1$ if $n$ even, $2$ if $n$ odd.